# c++ use a buffer in memory instead reading directly a file

Tags: c++, string, pointers, fopen, fread

I have this code that works fine:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
char id[5];
fread(id,sizeof(char),4,fp);
```

now I've changed something in my architecture, and instead the filename as fullpath of the file I have a char pointer that contains the data of the file.. so I don't need to read (fopen, etc..) but only to read the char* buffer...
how can I do this?
thanks in advance

Comment: You have to read the char buffer into what?? If you already have the data in the char buffer then just use it.

Comment: now I have char* myData that contains all the char buffer of the file... what function I need to use instead fread and fseek?
thanks

Comment: Just access the buffer directly? What exactly are you trying to do with it?

Comment: for example, fread in the code posted above, reads 4 chars and put into id variable, and after move to the fifth char... and after, if I call again fread, read the next data

Comment: TBH, I don't think that "c++" is apropriate here, as the code is nowhere close to C++... (tip: in C++, there are `string` and `fstream` to be used instad of `char*`/`[]` and `FILE`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to access a four character ID somewhere in the middle of your buffer. The easiest way to do this is just to copy the data into a new buffer and add a NULL terminator.

```
size_t index = 0;
// ...
char id[5];
memcpy(id, &myData[index], 4);
id[4] = '\0';
index += 4;
```

You can then read through your buffer sequentially by updating the index value every time you read something.

Answer (score 1):

```
char id[5];
strncpy(id,bfr,4);
id[4]='\0';
```

Where bfr is the buffer with your file data.

Also strongly advise you read the chapter on pointers and strings in K&R: The C Programming Language.

Comment: thanks, and to move the pointer like fseek? i need to remember the lenght each time I read?

Comment: @ghiboz Yes, you need to keep track of the index into the buffer manually. See my answer.

Comment: @ghiboz That's why I said you need to read the chapter. It is necesarry to understand how pointers work if using C. Simply bfr+5 will move the pointer by five. But this could be disastrous if you exceed the length of your buffer. Please read the chapter.